# MSVS2013: using FXC to compile HLSL files. When will SM4 hcs output of this be better than SM5 hcs?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, hlsl, compute-shader

Unfortunately, I can't share the code here (proprietary), but my issue is this: I have an HLSL (it's a gpu implementation of the Groestl hash function) file that can be compiled via FXC in both SM4 and SM5.  On my GPU, (AMD Radeon 7800 HD Series), I'm getting 3.6 MH/s with the SM4 hcs and 6.6 MH/s with the SM5 hcs.

Identical code, vastly superior performance with SM4 vs SM5.  Are there known cases where fxc is "stupid" when compiling SM5/are there known ways to trick it into not being stupid?

...or perhaps am I barking up the wrong tree and maybe this could be something unique to my GPU?  How would I check this?

Comment: Have you tried having FXC outputting the DXBC listing for both the SM4 and SM5 version and compared them?

Comment: Also consider downloading AMD GPUPerfStudio 3.3 and use the ShaderAnalyzer for GCN. This will show you the AMD GCN specific microcode for your GPU and will tell you where the differences lie.